# Monthly retention rate query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The monthly retention rates coming from the query are too low to be plausible. Here is my query:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date) AS obs_date,
    DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS prev_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM curr.obs_date) AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM curr.obs_date) AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.obs_date = prev.prev_date AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
  GROUP BY
    year, month
),
inter as (
SELECT
  year,
  month as month_,
  returning_user_count,
  total_users,
  (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
FROM
  returning_users
ORDER BY
year, month_
)


select * from inter
```

I think the LEFT join could potentially be problematic, but I am not sure. Also, maybe the monthly_user_counts CTE could be problematic in the way it is dealing with individual dates. However I can not think of another way to do this.
Is there any other way to calculate monthly retention rates?

Comment: example of data would be useful here - we have no idea what "too low" means (to you/and your data)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell The issue is when I add up new users for a month to the retained users from previous month, the total is significantly less than the figure for total active users for the month.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell there is no way that many users are reactivated from months older than the previous month!

Comment: how are you measuring "total active users"? could be an apple to pear comparison. Again, without sample data there's not much we can do than ask questions. Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PaulMaxwell  I am certain the definitions are consistent, can you please comment on the logic of the query and whether you think it is robust? That will help tremendously.

Comment: I think your join is incorrect try `curr.prev_date = prev.obs_date AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id` and see https://dbfiddle.uk/lqzizNge (**and** please notice I needed data to see that issue)

Comment: The OTHER problem is that because you have made this date specific instead of month specific - that would be why your result is too low. in other words you only recognise a returned user if they are exactly 1 month apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you have made the relationship between current to previous date specific and exactly 1 month apart. So a user that returns in (say) 3 weeks, or 27 days, is excluded. Use the first day of each month in the initial CTE then you cover all returning users:

I have no access to bigquery, so I have done this in Postgres:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    date_trunc('Month',event_date) AS obs_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM your_table
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    curr.obs_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN monthly_user_counts prev
  ON curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
    AND prev.obs_date = curr.obs_date - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
  GROUP BY
    curr.obs_date
),
inter AS (
  SELECT
    obs_date,
    returning_user_count,
    lag(total_users) over(order by obs_date) prev_total_users,
    total_users
  FROM returning_users
  ORDER BY
    obs_date
)

SELECT 
  *,
    (returning_user_count * 100.0 / prev_total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
FROM inter
```

You will need to refactor to Bigquery syntax.

- V1 see: https://dbfiddle.uk/dqzXpjFA
- v2 see: https://dbfiddle.uk/-K3zkPNr

Comment: May you live a blessed and happy life, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Do please remember, for future questions, that I needed data to "see" the issue and to propose a solution

Comment: One thing, this is giving retention rate as: returning users / total users of the current month. Whereas I want: returning users / total users of the previous month

Comment: Can you please assist with this final issue, I would be so grateful

Comment: see revised answer above, introduces lag()